# Javascript use value in another function

Tags: javascript, function

```
<script>
    function OnInit(s, e) {
        var input = s.GetInputElement();
        var MyValue = TextBox.GetValue(); // Question is here
        ASPxClientUtils.AttachEventToElement(input, "click", function (event) {
            s.SetText("");
        });
    }
        function onLostFocus(s, e) {
            if (s.GetText() == '')
                s.SetSelectedIndex(0);
        }
</script>
```

I want to use "MyValue " in onLostFocus function.

How can i get "MyValue" in onLostFocus function?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

You have to change the variable [**scope**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope) so its available for both functions.:

```
<script>
    var MyValue; // define the variable outside the function
    function OnInit(s, e) {
        var input = s.GetInputElement();
        MyValue = TextBox.GetValue();
        ASPxClientUtils.AttachEventToElement(input, "click", function (event) {
            s.SetText("");
        });
    }
    function onLostFocus(s, e) {
        if (s.GetText() == '')
            s.SetSelectedIndex(0);
    }
</script>
```